# Nodejs, restify, res.send() Cannot set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, restify

Each `res.send(200,` line when is reached according to the logic is working fine:

```
const implementation = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.rut) {
      const data = await someAPI();
      res.send(200, data); // WORKING
    } else {
      const data2 = await SomeAPI2();
      if (data2) {
        res.send(200, data2}); // WORKING
      }
      res.send(400, 'Error'); // ERROR
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(400, error);
  }
};
```

but when the code reach the line that uses `res.send(400` I'm getting this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
```

Why? I don't see that other `res.send()` lines are reached.

Comment: You should not call `res.send` 2 times for 1 request. How is that possible in your opinion, to send 200 data2 and then send 400 error? Add a few `return`s.

Answer (score 1):

So this happens because the execution reach the line

```
if (data2) {
  res.send(200, data2}); // WORKING
}
```

It sends the response, how its supposed to, but then the code continue its execution since there's nothing that tells it to stop (`res.send()` does not stop the execution) reaching the next line

```
res.send(400, 'Error'); // ERROR
```

But because the response object was already sent, it throws the error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
```

An easy way to fix this is to add a return before each `res.send`, that will stop the execution, thus not reaching the next line of code, for example

```
if (data2) {
  return res.send(200, data2});
}
return res.send(400, 'Error');
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though i don't like the way you wrote the code this could solve your issue:

```
const implementation = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.rut) {
      const data = await someAPI();
      res.send(200, data); // WORKING
    } else {
      const data2 = await SomeAPI2();
      if (data2) {
        res.send(200, data2}); // WORKING
      } else {
         res.send(400, 'Error'); // ERROR
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(400, error);
  }
};
```

FYI: 
i have added another else statement after you call the SomeAPI2().

Comment: Initially I had it like this way, with separetes if/else, happens the same

Comment: can you add res.end(); after the res.send(400, 'Error'); // ERROR.  and also remove the next parameter. Or if you are using it as a middleware make sure you call next() function!